# Como insertar un tipo de dato Date en Spring web MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Estoy viendo Spring web MVC en la escuela y haciendo un programa con operaciones CRUD intento ingresar una fecha pero me arroja **HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request** `description: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

Yo se que es el tipo de dato porque lo cambie a String en la clase Suscriptor y ya no marca error pero quisiera usar el tipo de dato que corresponde osea Date

Este es mi método en el controlador:

```
//Agregar registro
    @RequestMapping(value="agregar.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView Agregar(Suscriptor s){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tsuscriptores(nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno,servicio,fechaNacimiento,plan,estatus,idPlanes) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql, s.getNombre(), s.getApellidoPaterno(), s.getApellidoMaterno(), s.getServicio(), s.getFechaNacimiento(), s.getPlan(), s.getEstatus());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/acceso.htm");
    }
```

Esta es parte de mi clase Suscriptor:

```
public class Suscriptor {
int id;
String nombre;
String apellidoPaterno;
String apellidoMaterno;
String servicio;
Date fechaNacimiento;
String plan;
String estatus;
```

Y esta es mi etiqueta en el formulario:

```
    <h3><i>Fecha de nacimiento:</i></h3>
<input type="date" name="fechaNacimiento" class="form-control"  required />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré 5 posibles resultados en este enlace: https://localcoder.org/failed-to-convert-property-value-of-type-java-lang-string-to-required-type-java

Pero lo que a mi me funciono fue agregar esto a mi dispatcher ya que también se menciona que se necesita tener un servicio de conversión inicializado para poder usar el formateador automáticamente.

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```